# elm-package.json failing to load

Tags: intellij-idea, elm, intellij-14

I am attempting to create an Elm project in Intellij. To do this, I am using a fairly standard elm-package.json fle:

```
{
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "summary": "helpful summary of your project, less than 80 characters",
   "repository": "https://github.com/user/project.git",
   "license": "BSD3",
   "source-directories": [
       "."
   ],
   "exposed-modules": [],
   "dependencies": {
       "elm-lang/core": "5.1.1 <= v < 6.0.0",
       "elm-lang/html": "2.0.0 <= v < 3.0.0"
    },
    "elm-version": "0.18.0 <= v < 0.19.0"
}
```

I am trying to load this project, and am getting the following failure:

```
org.elm.workspace.ProjectLoadException: The 'type' field is 'null', but expected either 'application' or 'package'
```

There does not seem to be any documentation of this 'type' field! What is it? Where do I place it? More importantly, why wasn't it generated with the rest of the json file when I created it using elm-package install???

Comment: There is not `type` field in `elm-package.json`. There is however in `elm.sjon`, the manifest file for Elm 0.19. It might be that the intellij plugin upgraded its schema and just (incorrectly) aliased `elm.json` and `elm-package.json`. It would probably work if you use 0.19 instead. Is there any reason you can't?

Comment: Actually, there is nothing preventing me from using 0.19 -- except that I am still in the process of learning Elm and everything I have is geared to teaching 0.18. Everything I hear about 0.19 tells me that there are radical changes to the language itself, meaning that I cannot afford to use it while I am learning, 0.18 is safer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, though. I figured out what was going wrong and fixed it. I can now load the json file.

Comment: @FactorThree please add your solution for others to learn as well. Unless it was something very specific to your environment. In that case the question should be closed.